# Meu arraylist está retornando o mesmo valor em todos os "nós"

Tags: java, arraylist

Este codigo deveria pegar todos os elementos de um arquivo login.txt e colocar dentro de um array de usuário.

```
 public ArrayList<User> takeAll(){
    ArrayList<User> list = new ArrayList();
        User u = new User();
            String result = "";
            try {
            FileReader fr = new FileReader("C:\\Users\\vanes\\Documents\\WEBprog\\Archive\\login.txt");
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
            while (br.ready()) {
                result = br.readLine() + "\n";
                String divider[] = new String[2];//split                
                divider = result.split(";"); //split
                u.setName(divider[0]);
                u.setLogin(divider[1]);
                u.setPassword(divider[2]);
               // System.out.println(u.getName()+";"+u.getLogin()+";"+u.getPassword());
                list.add(u);
            }
            br.close();
            fr.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Erro");
        }
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) 
        System.out.println(list.get(i).getLogin());
    return list;    
}
```

Eu vejo que está sendo adicionado da forma como é para ser. Contudo, quando eu tento imprimir antes do "return list", o resultado aparece igual para todos os nós. Gostaria de saber onde está o erro.

Me parece que ele não está gravando corretamente dentro do while. Eu já testei o pedaço de código, em um outro lugar e funciona perfeitamente, essa parte do for, realmente, o erro aparenta estar dentro do while, mas eu não consigo ver.

Comment: Onde está o print?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é que você cria apenas um `User` fora do loop:

```
        User u = new User();
```

E dentro você altera os dados, mas sempre do mesmo `User`:

```
                u.setName(divider[0]);
                u.setLogin(divider[1]);
                u.setPassword(divider[2]);
```

Aí, se você descomentar o print vai ter a impressão que funcionou:

```
  // System.out.println(u.getName()+";"+u.getLogin()+";"+u.getPassword());
```

Mas ao final, na hora de "repassar a lista" vai ver que tem várias referências ao mesmo User.

A solução é criar um `new User()` **dentro** do *loop* e ir adicionando.

Answer (score 0):

Realmente está faltando um new a cada rodada no While ficaria como abaixo, deve resolver seu problema:

```
public ArrayList<User> takeAll(){
    ArrayList<User> list = new ArrayList();
        User u = new User();
            String result = "";
            try {
            FileReader fr = new FileReader("C:\\Users\\vanes\\Documents\\WEBprog\\Archive\\login.txt");
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
            while (br.ready()) {
                result = br.readLine() + "\n";
                String divider[] = new String[2];//split                
                divider = result.split(";"); //split
                u.setName(divider[0]);
                u.setLogin(divider[1]);
                u.setPassword(divider[2]);
               // System.out.println(u.getName()+";"+u.getLogin()+";"+u.getPassword());
                list.add(u);
                u = new User();
            }
            br.close();
            fr.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Erro");
        }
    for (User user : list) {
        System.out.println(user.getLogin());
    }

    return list;  
}
```